# Renombrar índices con un mismo nombre en un MultiIndex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Dispongo del siguiente DataFrame, el cual contiene fechas en que ciertos conductores realizaron pedidos para un centro concreto de trabajo:

```py
fechas = [Timestamp('2019-03-29 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-01-31 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-03-27 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-09-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-10-30 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-11-18 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-08-11 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-12-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-12-29 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-10-08 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-08-22 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-02-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-09-29 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-11 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-02-20 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-04-03 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-12-10 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-04-16 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-03-27 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-12-05 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-01-07 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-03-23 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-23 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-03-06 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-03-26 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-12-19 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-03-11 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-03-07 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-12-16 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-11-28 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-03-18 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-01-22 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-12-23 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-03-02 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-02-04 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-07-17 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-11-28 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-01-03 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-03-23 00:00:00')]
conductores = [1033, 1009, 1003, 1028, 1033, 1033, 1033, 1009, 1016, 1009, 1033, 1028, 1016, 1006, 1033, 1016, 1033, 1016, 1033, 1006, 1028, 1028, 1016, 1028, 1033, 1007, 1037, 1033, 1028, 1009, 1016, 1003, 1016, 1007, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1043, 1016, 1033]

datos = pd.DataFrame({'fecha': fechas, 'conductor':conductores})
```

Quiero realizar la gráfica de los distintos individuos que han trabajado por día en un solo centro al mes. Para ello primero agrupo datos por meses, conductores y años, para sacar la progresión anual tal que así:

```py
dias_cond_mes = (datos.groupby([datos.fecha.dt.month, "conductor", datos.fecha.dt.year])['fecha']
                 .nunique())
```

El resultado de esto debería agruparlo primero por meses y luego por años y aplicar sum() para contar el total, luego hacer unstack() para desapilar los datos y tendría la gráfica mostrando los meses en el eje X agrupados por años y la cantidad de días trabajados por los conductores por mes en el Y. El problema es que al usar el groupby .unique() retorna una Serie, que tiene como índices fecha,conductor,fecha y el ultimo vacío. No he sido capaz de cambiar estos valores ni se como agrupar esto de otra manera para obtener estos datos. Se me ocurre añadir una nueva columna solo con meses al DataFrame pero no se si habría otra manera mas sutil de hacerlo. Gracias.

Comment: Si el problema son los nombres del multiindex, simplemente puedes asignar los qu desees: `dias_cond_mes.index.names = ("mes", "conductor", "año")`

Comment: @FJSevilla No sabia que fuese posible acceder así a los índices, lo habia probado con columns, pero no funciono. Gracias

Comment: De nada, he creado una respuesta algo más detallada por si sirve para futuros usuarios. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente la aplicación de `nounique` sobre la columna `fecha`genera una Serie, con un MultiIndex como índice, el problema es que al agrupar por `datos.fecha.dt.month` y por `datos.fecha.dt.year`, `groupby` usa el nombre de la columna (`"fecha"`) en ambos casos como nombre para el índice correspondiente.

Que yo sepa no hay forma de evitar ésto directamente, pero es trivial en cambio renombrar  los niveles del índice posteriormente, mediante la property `pandas.Index.names`:

```
dias_cond_mes = (datos.groupby([datos.fecha.dt.month, "conductor", datos.fecha.dt.year])['fecha']
                 .nunique())

dias_cond_mes.index.names = ("mes", "conductor", "año")
```

o alternativamente con el método `pandas.Index.set_names`:

```
dias_cond_mes.index.set_names(("mes", "conductor", "año"), inplace=True)
```

> ```
> >>> dias_cond_mes
>
> mes  conductor  año 
> 1    1006       2018    1
>      1007       2018    1
>      1009       2020    1
>      1016       2018    1
>                 2019    1
>                 2020    1
>      1028       2019    1
> 2    1016       2019    1
> ...
>
> Name: fecha, dtype: int64
> ```

Lo que comentas como "último vacío" es en realidad los valores de la serie, puedes darle un nombre si quieres distinto de "fecha" (dado que una columna en un DataFrame es realmente una Serie):

```
dias_cond_mes.index.names = ("mes", "conductor", "año")
dias_cond_mes.name = "suma"
```

> ```
> >>> dias_cond_mes
>
> mes  conductor  año 
> 1    1006       2018    1
>      1007       2018    1
>      1009       2020    1
>      1016       2018    1
>                 2019    1
>                 2020    1
>      1028       2019    1
> 2    1016       2019    1
> ...
>
> Name: suma, dtype: int64
>
>
> >>> dias_cond_mes.to_frame()
>
>                     suma
> mes conductor año       
> 1   1006      2018     1
>     1007      2018     1
>     1009      2020     1
>     1016      2018     1
>               2019     1
>               2020     1
>     1028      2019     1
> 2   1016      2019     1
> ...
> ```